# failedPrecondition when using google Oauth2 Service Account

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail-api, jwt

There're  three types of google api client_id:
 1. Web Application
 2. Service Account
 3. Installed application

I have used `3. Installed application` successfullly base on [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client), but failed on `2. Service Account`. I wanna access my own gmail inbox with oauth2.0 `Credentials`.

```
import imaplib
import json
import urllib2
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
import os

reldir = os.path.dirname(os.path.relpath(__file__))
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(reldir, 'gmail_service.json')
OAUTH_SCOPE = "https://mail.google.com"
GMAIL_ADDRESS = 'my_gmail_address@gmail.com'

def jwt_oauth2():
    '''
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
    '''
    with open(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    private_key = data['private_key']
    client_email = data['client_email']
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        client_email,   private_key, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)

    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    try:
        gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
        threads = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

I got an exception same as the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307965/gmail-api-gives-failedprecondition-error). I encounter another exception while trying to add `sub=GMAIL_ADDRESS` into credentials:
`AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.`

I'm trying to figure out the problem, with `credentials` without `sub`:

```
>>> credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    client_email,   private_key, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
>>> http = credentials.authorize(Http())
>>> credentials.access_token
>>> credentials.refresh(http)
>>> credentials.access_token
u'ya29.pAGJjddCXjwsiHFN6hKU1yAkdWN7xMJbks5O76Pmrpe1hW1BbgwfZifjp81aDE55ALMVgjv-yBYiyQ'
>>> gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
>>> request = gmail_service.users().messages().list(userId='me')
>>> response = request.execute()
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "failedPrecondition",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Try to use `credentials` with `sub`:

```
>>> credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    client_email,   private_key, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE, sub=GMAIL_ADDRESS)
>>> http = credentials.authorize(Http())
>>> credentials.access_token
>>> credentials.refresh(http)
AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.
```

I found a similar question [Google OAuth2 Service Account HTTP/REST Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31124285/4497282), but I don't know much about `node.js`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947267/how-to-access-gmail-api/30955420#30955420

Comment: Service accounts cannot access @gmail.com mailboxes. You must use one of the other supported OAuth 2.0 authorization scenarios described at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534420/3377170 has more details.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the sub field where you specify the account which you want to impersonate.

Say, using your service Account, you want to get details of a user user@domain.com, the sub field should be populated as:

```
sub: user@domain.com
```

You should also make sure that you have given the service Account access to users in the domain.
Refer - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation